# Segmenting a polygon of non-uniform density into parts with equal number of points.

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have a complex polygon like this one.
[Polygon of Croatia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWlyM.png)

It is filled with about $16$k points with non-uniform density. I want to segment the polygon into parts that have the same number of points.
I understand this is a very complex problem but I don't need it to be mathematically perfect. I would be fine with ~$10\%$ error from wanted number of points in each segment.
To make my life easier I could first split the polygon into minimum number of convex parts.

The ideas I have so far:

- Pack the polygon with circles of varying radii based on the number of points within the circle and then use the centers of those circles to create a Voronoi diagram to fill in the gaps. I'm still not sure how I would achieve the packing part.
- Make repeated offsets of each convex part inwards and split the strip I get into segments based on the number of points inside it. Here's a simplified diagram of what I mean: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CDpT.png)
- Triangles?

Edit: A requirement I forgot to mention is that the groups of points would have to be close and not scattered across the polygon. I want each point in a segment to be relevant to that segment because I will be using a model to classify future points.

I'd also like for the algorithm to be deterministic ie. I want to get the same output each time I run it on the same points in the same order.
If I assume the points are distributed uniformly, how much easier does that make the problem?
I've been thinking about this for a while and I'd like to get some pointers and ideas from people that understand this kind of geometry better than me.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using a clustering algorithm?

Comment: Do you know the number of points? Do you know how many parts you want?

Comment: List the points north to south, and take the quantiles you want

Comment: I'm not sure how clustering would work since there are no relations between the points ie. there are no meaninful "clusters". My intuition might be wrong though.
I do know the number points. There are 16k points and I could decide that I want 300 segments so I can calculate the number in each segment.
Henry could you elaborate on how I would decide which points belong to which quantile? Or do I just count them until I get the number I want? Also there is an issue where the points might be close in north-south but far away in east-west.

Comment: Wait – you want the points in each part to be close? It doesn't say that anywhere in the statement of the problem. If that's what you want, you should edit a precise statement of that requirement into the body of your question.

Comment: Yes Gerry, you're right.  I updated the question.